# Plugin para Carousel comJQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso colocar um Carousel(Slider) em uma homepage, e pensei em fazer isso com JQuery, alguém pode me indicar algum plugin para fazer isso, sem que seja o carousel do bootstrap?

Comment: Sempre utilizo o https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ nos meus projetos.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o plugin Slick, http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Simples conforme segue pequeno exemplo:

```
<div class="slick-slider">
    <div>suaImagemAqui1</div>
    <div>suaImagemAqui2</div>
    <div>suaImagemAqui3</div>
  </div>
```

e o script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slick-slider').slick();
    });
```

e Pode ser personalizado com autoplay, velocidade, pontos de status, setas e vários outros atributos, documentação no link citado anteriormente.